# LoadBehavior for MS Word 2007 add-in being set to 2

Tags: com, ms-word, add-in

I have an add-in for MS Word. One of my users, who is on Word 2007, reports that the add-in is not being loaded. When she checks the COM add-ins list, it says "Load Behavior" is "Unloaded; Load at Startup" (value of 2 in LoadBehavior registry entry).

Yet when she checks the add-in's registry entry, LoadBehavior is set to 3 (Loaded; Load at Startup). The add-in is also not loaded at all.

Is there some reason for the discrepancy between what Word is reporting for the add-in, and what's in the registry, and is there a way to resolve it?

I have a hunch that Word has set a LoadBehavior value somewhere else on her system after the add-in crashed, but she is remote from me, and doesn't want me to remote control her computer to check myself.

**Edit**: Some additional info: if the user runs a macro to check my add-in in `Application.COMAddins`, `Connect` is set to `False`. However, updating this to `True` doesn't seem to have any effect. The property will stay True as long as Word is running, but if Word is restarted then it will revert to False (and the add-in is never loaded).

**More information**: The add-in had been disabled due to a crash, and put in the disabled add-ins list. **The user enabled the add-in** from the COM add-ins drop-down list, but the load behavior was then stuck on 2, despite the registry value being 3. WinWord.exe doesn't have any compatibility settings.

Also, I provide three add-ins: one for Word, one for Excel, and one for PowerPoint. The Excel and PowerPoint add-ins work fine on the user's computer. I test the add-in myself on XP, Vista, and 7 (32 and 64 bit). The user is on Vista 32 bit.

The Word add-in was working on the user's computer for about two years, but after a crash it was disabled, and the LoadBehavior was stuck on 2. The user actually tried uninstalling and reinstalling Office, but that didn't change the behavior.

**Solution**

0xA3's solution wasn't complete, but on the right track. It turns out that the user had installed a new antivirus program, which was disabling the add-in (silently! ::insert rant about overzealous AV::).

I also learned a valuable lesson: to some users, "Have you installed any new software" doesn't include antivirus programs. I'll have to change that question to, "Have you installed any new software, or any antivirus programs?"

Comment: Have you had a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx?

Comment: @Otaku: I hadn't seen that article, but I've tried almost everything in it. One thing I haven't tried is checking for AV problems, but the user says she hasn't installed any new software on her system. I'll ask about AV just to be sure, though.

Comment: The other thing to check is to see if it has been hard-disabled. In other words, check the drop-down in Trust Center that says "Com Add-ins" - the last drop-down in the combobox there says "disabled add-ins". Did your user hard-disable it? (this could happen as a result of a failure in your add-in and then a dialog on next startup that says a bunch of stuff like 'xxx caused a serious error, would you like to disable it' and your user just chose 'yes')

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind is Registry virtualization. If Winword.exe is configured to run with compatibility mode settings, modifications of the Registry might be written to a virtual Registry location. And yet another thing: Try analyzing with ProcMon to see what Registry keys are actually accessed.

Comment: Based on your comment above, now she needs to go back to the Options -> Addins -> COM Add-ins (in the dropdown) and then on your addin, ensure the checkmark is selected. Close Word, reopen and everything should be fine after that.

Comment: Based on your bolded statement above, what this means that re-loading your add-in continues to cause the LoadBehavior to be set to 2. The failure here is in the add-in, not exactly in Word. Is there anything unique about the user's machine that makes the add-in fail (for example, is it x64 Word and everyone else is using x86)? The add-in is likely not accounting for this kind of failure scenario, hence the continued setting to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by Otaku, the problem seems to be that the add-in cannot be loaded and therefore is disconnected. It might due be an incomplete/corrupt installation of the add-in, a missing dependency or incorrect/missing registration of a COM component.

It's hard to give you more concrete tips, but here is a list of trouble-shooting tools that you might want to use during Word startup:

- DebugView from Sysinternals, run as Administrator, with *Capture Global* and `Capture Kernel` enabled.
- fuslogvw.exe to check for missing assemblies (assuming your add-in is written in .NET)
- DependencyWalker to see for missing native dlls
- Process Monitor to check for missing files/registry entries

> Is there some reason for the discrepancy between what Word is reporting for the add-in, and what's in the registry, and is there a way to resolve it?

The reason for the discrepancy between the Registry and the actual Word setting is most likely that the current add-in state (loaded, but disconnected) is not stored in the Registry at all because the user has no sufficient permissions to change the HKLM Registry key. The LoadBehavior remains 3 in the Registry, and on next Word startup Word will try again to load and connect the add-in.

Comment: As I said in the question, the user is remote from me, and won't let me do remote control on her computer. The add-in has been uninstalled and re-installed, as has Office. The other two add-ins (for Excel and PPT) are working fine. The entry is marked with LoadBehavior 3 in the registry. She can load the addin via Application.COMAddins, and set the Connect value to true. That doesn't have any effect, though.

Comment: @Ryan Ginstrom: We don't know what your add-in is doing, but obviously there is a difference in what the add-in is doing when loaded into Word as compared to when loaded into Excel or PowerPoint. Btw, what technology are you using for your add-in?

Comment: They're all written in C++. Yes, there could be something wrong with the add-in itself, but she used it for two years or so without problems, and many other people are using it now. Also, it's never even getting loaded, so it has no chance to crash (the first action in OnConnection is to write to a log file, and that never gets created). The logging code is exactly the same across the three add-ins.

Comment: @Ryan Ginstrom: Note that your add-in code is never reached when a dependency is missing or has an incorrect version. Still, the add-in crashes on load (from Word's point of view). Or it might be that there is a problem in some constructor somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Addins can be registered in the USER hive or the LOCAL MACHINE hive, same folder in each.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\Your addin name

or

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\Your addin name

be sure to check both.

Comment: Thanks. My add-in's RGS file is set to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, but I'm going to ask the user to check just in case.

Comment: Update -- there was no entry in HKCU.

Comment: Just remembered one other place to check. Office 2007 had this really WIERD scheme whereby reg entries would be created in the HKLM hive and when word loaded, it'd copy them over to the user hive. Check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\User Settings\Word_Core\Create\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins and see if there are any entries in there.

Comment: As far as I know, they ditched that with Office 2010. I'm not seeing those entries anymore in any case.

Comment: That looked really promising, but unfortunately, nothing was set for my add-in there (Word_Core..).

Comment: Have you tried Otaku's comment of checking if the addin as been disabled? that's about the only other thing I can think of. If that doesn't work, might have to pull out regmon/filemon and see if those registry entries are actually getting read as you think they should be. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

FYI : I was having similar issue with Excel AddIn. Excel "blacklisted" the add-in due to an error (which has not necessarily generated any error message). Go to: AddIns > "Disabled items" > Enable Addin resovled the issue for me.